# WSMModelData[] can not find my model

Tags: system-modeler

I have something like this in my notebook (SystemModeler is not running):

```
Needs["WSMLink`"]
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
(* "F:\\WMath\\DCmotor" *)

model = "DCmotor";
WSMModelData[model, "Diagram"]
```

> During evaluation `WSMLink::nomod: The class DCmotor was not found.` - !!!!!!

But when I run SystemModeler and only load my model everything is ok.
That is not the case when I use models from SystemModeler examples.
The question is: how to show Mathematica where my *.mo file is without launching SystemModeler?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution! 
One must use Import[] function like this: 
Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "DCmotor.mo"}], "ModelicaModel"].
And all functions connected with SystemModeler (WSMModelData[] etc.) work fine in Mathematica without launching the SystemModeler application. But there is no description in Mathematica help about Import[] func - about the option "ModelicaModel". I found this in LEGOSegway - Wolfram SystemModeler example on the web.

Comment: after you load the WSMLink package you will have the documentation for the .mo file format (among others): http://reference.wolfram.com/system-modeler/WSMLink/ref/format/MO.html